# java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture on Android 5.0

Tags: java, android, gradle

I have a package built for Java 8 using `java.time.{Clock,Instant}` and `java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture`. I am trying to find a way to run it on Android 5.0 with minor modifications, by using desugaring as mentioned in https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table, but it's failing with:

```
Failed resolution of: Ljava/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture;
```

I tried including the following in `gradle.build`:

```
implementation 'net.sourceforge.streamsupport:android-retrofuture:1.7.4'
```

but it's still not working, it seems related to the fact that the package names are `java9.*` instead of `java.*`.

Is there a convenient way to make my package work on Android 5.0 without rewriting it to not use these APIs?

Comment: This is the reason why Kotlin is so popular on Android. You can use Kotlin coroutines instead. I would suggest writing this functionality in Kotlin. Luckily Java and Kotlin can coexist in a codebase.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't afford to rewrite the package in Kotlin right now :(

Comment: Desugaring is the best you can do.  If that won't cut it, there's no way.

Comment: This is unfortunate... What would be the quickest alternative? Are there any libraries that implement the same functionality in a similar way (to make migration quick) but is compatible with Android 5.0?

Comment: Try https://github.com/SgtSilvio/android-retrofix